# How to make a button like link with hover effects?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the color of the text turn to black not only when I move the mouse cursor to the text, but also when the cursor enters the whole button area?

```css
.button {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #e7dd84;
  background-color: rgba(236, 229, 167, 0.2);
  transition: 0.35s;
}
.button a, active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e7dd84;
}
.button a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.button:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
  transition: 0.35s;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="first.html">Go to site</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrong syntax `.button a, active`, and **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/cttxfw12/)** is how I would do it.

Comment: @Pangloss, I've been doing it wrong all this time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of styling the `<div>`, I suggest to do it on the `<a>` tag directly.

I would use inline block, so that you don't need to specify the `width`, as inline block has the ability of *shrink-to-fit* based on length of the text. And on the container all you need is `text-align:center` to center that *button* horizontally.

Hover on the **edges** of the *button* you'll see the link also becomes available, because we set `padding` on it directly. Unless your original demo, you'll have to hover on the **text** to be able to click. This small improvement makes it more accessible, less confusing.

I also moved the class `button` onto the `<a>`, and add `container` to the `<div>`.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hw3x2Lq/)**

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(236, 229, 167, 0.2);
  border: 2px solid #e7dd84;
  color: #e7dd84;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: 0.35s;
}
.button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="button" href="first.html">Go to site</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean like this?

```css
.button
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 15%;
 padding: 8px;
 border: 2px solid;
 border-color: #e7dd84;
 background-color: rgba(236,229,167,0.2);
 transition: 0.35s;

}
.button a, active
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #e7dd84;

}

.button:hover a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;

}

.button:hover
{
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
 border-color: white;
 transition: 0.35s;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="first.html">Go to site</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the color change to the link when you hover on the button.

Currently you have given the color to change when hoverd on the link inside the button.

Check updated snippet.

```css
.button
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 15%;
 padding: 8px;
 border: 2px solid;
 border-color: #e7dd84;
 background-color: rgba(236,229,167,0.2);
 transition: 0.35s;

}
.button a, active
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #e7dd84;

}

.button:hover a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;

}

.button:hover
{
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
 border-color: white;
 transition: 0.35s;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="first.html">Go to site</a>
 </div>
```